# Using container in react redux app produces unwanted renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am using the container, component folder structure in my react app, where the container is used to connect the redux store to presentational components but as app grows larger there are many unwanted renders in components in spite of using **pure components**. Do we need to use container for react apps on using redux or can we use redux **connect** method on every component?
how to avoid unwanted rerenders on components and only re-render the props changed component is there any solution or pattern for this?

Comment: Please show minimal examples [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your containers will be called much not frequently than the components they contain. This is not a bad thing, because the containers themselves won't trigger any changes to the virtual DOM every time they are called. Is only if the inner component receives new props, it may require any actual work to be done.

Comment: In the other hand, if you can see that your components remembers unnecessarily, try using one of the why did you render debuggers to find out why.